# LibreOffice menu bar doesn't function

Tags: 12.10, libreoffice

I've recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 and LibreOffice in this OS doesn't work correctly. Any time I click something from the menu bar (e.g. `File -> Print` or `Save As`), nothing happens. It looks like a window is appearing after my click, but is hidden somewhere.

Please help me fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: You're probably seeing this problem, please update that bug report if you have any new information to add, thanks! https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1064962

Comment: I had the same issue. I am glad this post was here regardless of the policies articulated above. This helped me find hope of a solution.

Answer (score 3):

See also https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1069971. Same/similar issue. lo-menubar not installed (and should not be needed under 12.10?) and not installable (errors out on apt-get install).

Answer (score 2):

This will not fix the issue but might help to deal with it. When LibreOffice is opened, open the HUD menu by taping on the ALT-key. Then hide the HUD by taping on the ALT-key again. See if the menu reappears and if the buttons are functional.

Edited:
Bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1064962

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install lo-menubar` noobslab advice to get it working see if it works